# Making GIFs with Java

Tags: java, beginner, image, animation

I wrote a Java class to make a GIF animation from a list of images. The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/ha-shine/Giffer/tree/daf15de9efde7a88e60bd5ff9d1f5b2e47153a48).

I am pretty new with GitHub, so I would be very glad if you can give critiques regarding my project structure.

```
package shine.htetaung.giffer;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.imageio.IIOException;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOInvalidTreeException;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataNode;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;

/*
 * Giffer is a simple java class to make my life easier in creating gif images.
 * 
 * Usage :
 * There are two methods for creating gif images
 * To generate from files, just pass the array of filename Strings to this method
 * Giffer.generateFromFiles(String[] filenames, String output, int delay, boolean loop)
 * 
 * Or as an alternative you can use this method which accepts an array of BufferedImage
 * Giffer.generateFromBI(BufferedImage[] images, String output, int delay, boolean loop)
 * 
 * output is the name of the output file
 * delay is time between frames, accepts hundredth of a time. Yeah it's weird, blame Oracle
 * loop is the boolean for whether you want to make the image loopable.
 */

public abstract class Giffer {

    // Generate gif from an array of filenames
    // Make the gif loopable if loop is true
    // Set the delay for each frame according to the delay (ms)
    // Use the name given in String output for output file
    public static void generateFromFiles(String[] filenames, String output, int delay, boolean loop)
        throws IIOException, IOException
    {
        int length = filenames.length;
        BufferedImage[] img_list = new BufferedImage[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(filenames[i]));
            img_list[i] = img;
        }

        generateFromBI(img_list, output, delay, loop);
    }

    // Generate gif from BufferedImage array
    // Make the gif loopable if loop is true
    // Set the delay for each frame according to the delay, 100 = 1s
    // Use the name given in String output for output file
    public static void generateFromBI(BufferedImage[] images, String output, int delay, boolean loop)
            throws IIOException, IOException
    {
        ImageWriter gifWriter = getWriter();
        ImageOutputStream ios = getImageOutputStream(output);
        IIOMetadata metadata = getMetadata(gifWriter, delay, loop);

        gifWriter.setOutput(ios);
        gifWriter.prepareWriteSequence(null);
        for (BufferedImage img: images)
        {
            IIOImage temp = new IIOImage(img, null, metadata);
            gifWriter.writeToSequence(temp, null);
        }
        gifWriter.endWriteSequence();
    }

    // Retrieve gif writer
    private static ImageWriter getWriter() throws IIOException
    {
        Iterator<ImageWriter> itr = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif");
        if(itr.hasNext())
            return itr.next();

        throw new IIOException("GIF writer doesn't exist on this JVM!");
    }

    // Retrieve output stream from the given file name
    private static ImageOutputStream getImageOutputStream(String output) throws IOException
    {
        File outfile = new File(output);
        return ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outfile);
    }

    // Prepare metadata from the user input, add the delays and make it loopable
    // based on the method parameters
    private static IIOMetadata getMetadata(ImageWriter writer, int delay, boolean loop)
        throws IIOInvalidTreeException
    {
        // Get the whole metadata tree node, the name is javax_imageio_gif_image_1.0
        // Not sure why I need the ImageTypeSpecifier, but it doesn't work without it
        ImageTypeSpecifier img_type = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(img_type, null);
        String native_format = metadata.getNativeMetadataFormatName();
        IIOMetadataNode node_tree = (IIOMetadataNode)metadata.getAsTree(native_format);

        // Set the delay time you can see the format specification on this page
        // https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/gif_metadata.html
        IIOMetadataNode graphics_node = getNode("GraphicControlExtension", node_tree);
        graphics_node.setAttribute("delayTime", String.valueOf(delay));
        graphics_node.setAttribute("disposalMethod", "none");
        graphics_node.setAttribute("userInputFlag", "FALSE");

        if(loop)
            makeLoopy(node_tree);

        metadata.setFromTree(native_format, node_tree);

        return metadata;
    }

    // Add an extra Application Extension node if the user wants it to be loopable
    // I am not sure about this part, got the code from StackOverflow
    // TODO: Study about this
    private static void makeLoopy(IIOMetadataNode root)
    {
        IIOMetadataNode app_extensions = getNode("ApplicationExtensions", root);
        IIOMetadataNode app_node = getNode("ApplicationExtension", app_extensions);

        app_node.setAttribute("applicationID", "NETSCAPE");
        app_node.setAttribute("authenticationCode", "2.0");
        app_node.setUserObject(new byte[]{ 0x1, (byte) (0 & 0xFF), (byte) ((0 >> 8) & 0xFF)});

        app_extensions.appendChild(app_node);
        root.appendChild(app_extensions);
    }

    // Retrieve the node with the name from the parent root node
    // Append the node if the node with the given name doesn't exist
    private static IIOMetadataNode getNode(String node_name, IIOMetadataNode root)
    {
        IIOMetadataNode node = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < root.getLength(); i++)
        {
            if(root.item(i).getNodeName().compareToIgnoreCase(node_name) == 0)
            {
                node = (IIOMetadataNode) root.item(i);
                return node;
            }
        }

        // Append the node with the given name if it doesn't exist
        node = new IIOMetadataNode(node_name);
        root.appendChild(node);

        return node;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] img_strings = {"sample-images/cool.png", "sample-images/cry.png", "sample-images/love.png", "sample-images/oh.png"};

        try
        {
            Giffer.generateFromFiles(img_strings, "sample-images/output.gif", 40, true);
        } catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Peter Rader that static factories are not a good pattern. For this particular task I would be inclined to use a builder pattern. In particular, I would quite like to have a `BufferedImage... images` varargs parameter somewhere, and IMO the cleanest way of doing that would be for it to be the sole parameter of a constructor.

---

`generateFromBI` opens an output stream, but doesn't seem to close it. The "best practices" way of doing this nowadays would be a [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). I haven't used Java 8, so I can't do better than to point you at the docs.

---

> ```
>     // Not sure why I need the ImageTypeSpecifier, but it doesn't work without it
>     ImageTypeSpecifier img_type = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
> ```

Full marks for honest commenting, but you may not have realised that you're making a dangerous assumption. What if the image isn't of `TYPE_INT_ARGB`? The more robust way of doing this would be to create a fresh `IIOMetadata` for each image, using `new ImageTypeSpecifier(img)` to create an appropriate `ImageTypeSpecifier` for each one.

---

The `disposalMethod` is hard-coded to `"none"`. It would be nice to make this configurable, preferably via an enum rather than raw strings, in particular because using `"doNotDispose"` opens up the possibility of optimising the images to use transparency on areas which don't change.

(And on the subject of exposing nice types rather than cryptic raw data, Java 8 provides [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html), which is nicer than raw centiseconds).

---

> ```
>        app_node.setUserObject(new byte[]{ 0x1, (byte) (0 & 0xFF), (byte) ((0 >> 8) & 0xFF)});
> ```

is a bit odd. It seems to be saying *"The structure here is very important and you might want to change it, but I won't document it for you"*. I would either use magic `new byte[] { 1, 0, 0 }` or pull out the parameters as `new byte[]{ foo, bar, baz }` with more descriptive names.

---

Finally, some of the method names seem slightly misleading to me. `get` connotes *"this object already exists and is stored somewhere"*, but several of these `getXYZ` methods are actually creating (or getting, with a creation fallback). I would favour renaming with a `create` or a `findOrCreate` prefix as appropriate for each case.

Comment: These are all really useful feedbacks. Thanks! I will be refactoring my code soon.

Answer (score 2):

I expected to find a oldschool factory pattern, not a pseudo static-method-factory-pattern ... static methods always makes me a little bit sad because you can not mock static-programming-units in tests very well.

The method `getWriter` is essential! It makes no sense to load the class if `getWriter` fails anyway. Also classes shall report problems as early as possible. See this:

```
public abstract class Giffer {
   private static final ImageWriter defaultWriter = 
       ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("gif").next();
   ...
}
```

The class would fail as early as possible.

Instead of set the Files via `String` there is a better matching class for this: `File`.

Try to follow the [packagename conventions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the advices! Much appreciated. I will look into the factory patterns. Any advice on how to implement them in my case?

Comment: Finally i read what i wrote and it sounds shattering, i am sorry. I am sure it works great. Its more documentation i would expect. Nice work.